# codeigniter 3 error connecting to db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I run wamp and try to connect to db but I got

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

Few faqs / what I've done:

1. I autoloaded the database library in config.php
2. my phpMyAdmin doesn't have any username and pass set
3. this is the setting in database.php

> ```
> $db['default'] = array(
>   'dsn'   => '',
>   'hostname' => 'localhost',
>   'username' => '',
>   'password' => '',
>   'database' => 'ciintro',
>   'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
>   'dbprefix' => '',
>   'pconnect' => TRUE,
>   'db_debug' => TRUE,
>   'cache_on' => FALSE,
>   'cachedir' => '',
>   'char_set' => 'utf8',
>   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
>   'swap_pre' => '',
>   'autoinit' => TRUE,
>   'encrypt' => FALSE,
>   'compress' => FALSE,
>   'stricton' => FALSE,
>   'failover' => array(),
>   'save_queries' => TRUE
> );
> ```

Comment: try a simple mysql_connect() in index.php and see if that works

Comment: I solved this, the username should equal to 'root'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'username' => ''`,

should be

`'username' => 'root'`,

check username.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are newer to codeigniter.

'username' => 'root'    ( root or whatever you set for PHPMYADMIN.)

'password' => 'password' ( password or whatever you set for PHPMYADMIN.)